# how to create a multi worksheet excel jasper report?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, worksheet

how to create a multi worksheet excel jasper report??

can i only specify in the jrxml file???

or i need to do some special coding in java???

Answer (score 0):

You need do some extra works on the 'export to Excel' function,write your report data sheet by sheet.

Comment: Here is more info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977658/how-do-you-export-a-jasperreport-to-an-excel-file-with-multiple-worksheets