# Exceeding the row limit of 65536 in Excel in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

While hitting the database I am getting more than 80000 records. I am using JasperReports to export those into an Excel, but an Excel can hold a row limit of 65536.

How can I export all records in single report or how can I create a new excel when ever it exceeds 65536? I gone through this link but I am not getting things:
[Is it possible to see more than 65536 rows in Excel 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197762/is-it-possible-to-see-more-than-65536-rows-in-excel-2007).

Here is the main problem: list object contains more than 80000 records. How can I divide the list object into two JasperPrint objects when ever it exceed the 65536 rows?

If i am able to divide the list object into two JasperPrint objects then we can happily add the two `JasperPrint` objects to one collection then we can add the collection object to `JRExporter` object here is the code to add two `JasperPrint` objects to collection:
   [How do you export a JasperReport to an Excel file with multiple worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977658/how-do-you-export-a-jasperreport-to-an-excel-file-with-multiple-worksheets).

This is my code so far:

```
JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                            confirmList);
                    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                            .loadObject(reportPath);
                    Map parameters = new HashMap();
                    parameters.put("title", "Reports for "
                            + "confirmed");
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                            jasperReport, parameters, datasource);
```

Can anyone please guide me how to do this?

Comment: why not create a new sheet once the current one exceeds 65536 rows?

Comment: You need to cut them onto a new work sheet.

Comment: if you provide the sample code in jasper reports that's great help for me  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977658/how-do-you-export-a-jasperreport-to-an-excel-file-with-multiple-worksheets

Comment: Generally spoken that much data is not suitable for a human processable document (too big, slow). Condense the data: do statistical analysis, curve fitting, deviation ranges.

Comment: please provide any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Excel specifications and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291)

> Applies to: Excel 2010
>
> **Worksheet size  1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns**

**Recommendation**:

Upgrade to Excel 2010